# make data in store available to all components in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I want to have logged in user as an object saved in store and available for all components in my app.

Even though i saved the user object as a state in the store in one component, when the route is changed, the previous state and user become empty again in other `connected` components.

Is there a way to persist the state in store when the routes are changed?

Comment: how are you changing routes?  Using `Link` or just changing the address in the browser?

Comment: @davin both, ideally

Comment: When you change the address in the browser, the page reloads and you can't persist the state.  When you navigate using a `Link` from `react-router`, the page does not reload and your state will persist